# mongoose not recognizing the collection by name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'mcfly');

db.once('open', function() {

    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String
    });

    var col = db.model('mathpeep', schema);

    col.find({firstname: 'hey'}, function(err, Col) {
        console.log(Col);
    });
})
```

I have mongod running properly, and I ran "mango" and inputted a couple entries to the database "mcfly" inside the collection "mathpeep". This code is basically copied from another place where it works, down to variable names, so I have no clue what's wrong.

The problem is that my db looks like this:

```
> use mcfly
switched to db mcfly
> db.createCollection('mathpeep')
{ "ok" : 1 }
> show collections
mathpeep
system.indexes
> db.mathpeep.insert({firstname: 'hey', lastname: 'ayy'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.mathpeep.insert({firstname: 'aaa', lastname: 'aaaaa'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.mathpeep.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5592e96566cf1404577ebe1b"), "firstname" : "hey", "lastname" : "ayy" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5592e97b66cf1404577ebe1c"), "firstname" : "aaa", "lastname" : "aaaaa" }
>
```

Yet the code above returns an empty file (?). The same happens when I try saving a file using that schema: the script finishes without problem, but when I check the database using the shell, nothing was saved. I'm copying the code from somewhere else, that saves and reads from the database just fine. I also ran the mongoose install again, if it did not install correctly then I have no clue how to fix it.

There are no errors: When I run the script, it prints this:

```
[]
```

And that's all that happens.

I can only assume I'm connecting somewhere else or something, hence the question name.

Thanks

Comment: Edited the question name to be more useful to unlucky souls like me

Answer (score 8):

I think it's because mongoose adds an `s` to make it plural. So it's checking in the collection `mathpeeps`. To explicitly tell the collection name use third argument:

```
var col = db.model('mathpeep', schema, 'mathpeep');
```

---

To make sure what's the query it's making add this in you code:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

Comment: This solved it. Any idea why it does such an incomprehensible thing?

Comment: It's the default behaviour: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting like this:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/mcfly');
```

And access your collection like this:

`var col = mongoose.model('mathpeep', new Schema({ firstname: String, lastname: String }),`
`'mathpeep' ) //here goes your collection name;`

Comment: The first line only caused error, but the second line (like in the other answer) solved it. Thanks a lot to both of you

Comment: Oh, my bad, it was probably because I didn't put the default port (27017).